# android how to save an object to file?

Tags: android, file, object, save

Does someone know how to save and restore an object to a file on android ?

Answer (score 11):

Open a file using openFileOutput() ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal ), than use an ObjectOutputStream ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html ) to write your object to a file.

Use their evil twin openFileInput() and ObjectInputStream() to reverse the process.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if You want to save file on internal or external media. For both situation there are great samples on Android DEV site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html - this should definetly help

Comment: I want to save it to internal. Im watching ObjectOutputStream now and its look interesting but dont know why, cannot get "fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);" to work, it doesnt accept my String filename parameter... what's the hell ????

Comment: Ive found out that its a problem of context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested example of @yayay's suggestion. Note that using `readObject()` returns an `Object`, so you will need to cast, although the compiler will complain that it is an unchecked cast. I can still run my code fine though. You can read more about the casting issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873190/warning-unchecked-unchecked-cast-when-casting-object-to-arrayliststring).

Just make sure that your class (in my case, `ListItemsModel`) is serializable, because the `writeObject()` will serialize your object, and the `readObject()` will deserialize it. If it is not (you get no persistence and the logcat throws a `NotSerializableException`), then make sure your class implements `java.io.Serializable`, and you're good to go. Note, no methods need implementing in this interface. If your class cannot implement `Serializable` and work (e.g. 3rd party library classes), [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) helps you to serialize your object.

```
private void readItems() {

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput("groceries");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            ArrayList<ListItemsModel> list = (ArrayList<ListItemsModel>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}

private void writeItems() {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("groceries", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(itemsList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```