# "Warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast" when casting Object to ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, casting, java-8

Strange situation - below is the code:

```
ArrayList<String[]> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
Object[] obj = new Object[]{"str", listArr};

String str = (String) obj[0];//OK
ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) obj[1];//warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
```

When project is built (with compiler option `-Xlint:unchecked` in project properties), I get one warning:

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
>                          ArrayList list = (ArrayList) obj[1];
>    required: ArrayList
>    found:
>   Object

But casting String in the same way is OK. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the compiler can not verify the internal types at the list level, so you need to first verify for list. And the internal types individually.

Instead of  `ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) obj[1];`

It should be 
`ArrayList<?> list = (ArrayList<?>) obj[1];`

Comment: OK, but how later change it to `ArrayList<String[]>` type, so I could pass it to methods, which require `ArrayList<String[]>` (otherwise the code will not compile)? Or I should just ignore this warning?

Comment: @Ernestas Gruodis: This is a limitation that can’t be solved without deep, incompatible changes to the Java language *and* the JVM. But the question is why you are using `Object[]` at all. Java’s type system allows you to keep track of object’s types and if you deliberately decide to drop these type information you shouldn’t complain about lost type information…

Comment: `Object[]` because method returns various data types. That means the question is answered.

Comment: In my case, I have to use `readObject()` method from `ObjectInputStream`, so by default it comes back as an `Object`... so changing it to the right kind of object I need is tricky.

Answer (score 2):

This is because if you try to cast Integer to String you will get ClassCastException at runtime. But there will be no ClassCastException here:

```
    ArrayList<Integer[]> listArr = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) obj[1];
```

Comment: Yes you did, but the runtime cannot know, thats why it is warning you that it cannot enforce the generic type parameter of the cast.

Comment: I believe `ArrayList<Integer[]>` is a concrete type generic.  To avoid the aforementioned issue, one must do `ArrayList<?>`

Comment: Hey! I have two questions regarding your answer: if no ClassCastException is thrown in your example, what would actually happen? Undefined behaviour? Random values? And secondly: does this mean, that writing my own wrapper class for `ArrayList<String> `(or whatever the Collection is you want to have) is a valid way out of the issue? I mean, if I had something like `MyStringList` which internally would store an `ArrayList<String>`, then it again could throw the classCastException at runtime - is this a legit way out of the problem?

Comment: Rethinking: is this reasoning correct: the cast will go through without a ClassCastException, but later on when we try to do something with one of those elements (which won't be of the appropriate type, we actually will get a ClassCastExcpetion, right?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler complains

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) obj[1]
```

because a cast is a runtime check. So at runtime your `ArrayList<String[]>` could be a `ArrayList<Whatever[]>`, because the type of obj is unknown.